# People keep leaving the company. How to know if there is something going on?

Tags: united-kingdom, company

In the past few months a lot of people (mostly BAs, Account Managers and people in management) have left the company I work for.
While this is pretty normal for developers I don't know about management.

There are no bad news or rumors, "everything is going great" and we have "a lot of new jobs coming in". Also the company keep hiring new people (an average of 2/week).

However I've had experience in the past of "everything going great" and the company suddenly announcing shutting down.

Comment: Who are those quotes coming from?

Comment: "Should I be worried?" is a really open ended and opinion-based question. You might want to revise your post to be more specific.

Comment: @AffableAmbler from recent company meetings and announcements

Comment: The change from "should I be worried" to "how to know if there is something going on" makes this a little easier to respond to. I think @MisterPositive's answer below is a good response to the edited version because it points out specific things to look for when deciding if something is going on.

Comment: This is rather speculative really.  But IMO it is generally not a good sign when people who know things start leaving in droves.  It could be a silent layoff if those particular positions are not being backfilled.  It could be a toxic manager above these folks, or they had privy to information that you did not.  If you had a decent relationship with any of the people that left you could reach out.  Had a silent layoff one time.  Still replaced my position when I left, but the ones let go in the silent layoff were not replaced (they were management and program management BTW).  Kept the devs

Answer (score 7):

> Should I be worried?

### No need to worry.

This is just the normal ebb and flow of a company.  Sometimes people leave in batches (*not related*).  In other cases a high ranking employee (VP for example) will leave and take some of their main people with them.

You worry when there is no work coming in, or hiring stops, or if your company is public the stock takes a hit.  Other red flags to watch out for are if the company **stops giving raises** or **paying out bonuses**.

Based on the *details of your question*, I would say not to worry.

Comment: ``stops giving raises`` None of the companies I've worked for have had automatic annual raises. Everyone had to "request" one and provide reasoning for it. Only rarely were they approved. Maybe it's regional.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen It probably is.  I have never had to ask for a pay rise.  It's always been given at a fixed time every year, based on a performance review.

Comment: In all the companies I worked I always get at least inflation raises.  Basically will be fired if you are so bad they want to deny inflation raises.

Comment: In Finland, inflation raises are negotiated every 3 or so years by each field's (for example technology industry) labour unions and they will be enacted by the government. Everyone in that field, even if they are not in the union, will get the raise if one will happen. Generally those raises are anything between 0 - 2 %, but mostly roughly 1 %. Those cannot be negotiated by the employee or employer, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm reading too far in to your question, but for me, this doesn't stop at "worry or don't worry." After all, worry either makes us sick, or motivates us to change. So, instead, **consider the potential ways this could motivate your behaviors:**

- If there is a lot of staff turnover, that can mean a lot of open positions. Most employers like to fill from within, so they're maintaining a relationship with their people and are able to evaluate candidates they already know vs externals. Maybe this is a good time to consider keeping an eye out for a more senior position or changing departments in a way that supports your career goals
- Alternately, this may mean you are suddenly surrounded by new people. Maybe this is a good time for you and other experienced staffers to suggest revising or adding more formality to documentation, procedures, etc. in order to support the newbies. You can show your initiative by offering to take the lead on this, and/or offering to help onboard or mentor the new staff
- It's also a good time to network outside your company - that way, if things do take a turn for the worse, you're already geared up and ready to hit the ground running with your new job search.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question...

Comment: I think you're right, I did not directly answer the question but projected past it. Maybe my text should have been in a comment instead of an answer?